# UITextView not becoming first responder for iphone X ios 11

Tags: swift, textview, uitextfield, ios11, iphone-x

textview isn't becoming first responder when using iphone X but it works fine for iphone 7 and other devices. I have set the delegate for the textview and use `textViewDidBeginEditing` delegate method. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
descTextView.delegate = self

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView){
     textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to call `becomeFirstResponder` inside `textViewDidBeginEditing`. `textViewDidBeginEditing` is only called when the text field has already become the first responder.

Comment: Where would you call becomeFirstResponder then? Even if I comment that out, it's not working.

Comment: You don't need to call `becomeFirstResponder`. The text view will become first responder when the user taps on the text view. If you want some other code (say a button press) to trigger the text view then call `becomeFirstResponder` on the text view in the button handler or other relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to call 
  `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` 

 in your viewWillAppear() method like this,

```
    func viewWillAppear() { 
       textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

if you can add more info about what is the previous event? or when you want your textView to become first responder? that will be easy to understand your requirement.

Comment: I want the textView to become first responder when a user taps on the textview box to type. It was working fine previously until I updated to ios 11. My only concern with calling textView.becomeFirstResponder in viewWillAppear would be that the keyboard would appear as soon as the screen loads.